# How to sort it better?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays, both are multidimensional with same number of elements and same values, which are on different positions (those values are actually ID-s from my database, so one ID appears only once). How can I sort second array with values which are in first array?

For example - if first array looks like:

```
$array1[0][0] = 1;
$array1[0][x] = it doesn't matter what's here
$array1[1][0] = 4;
$array1[1][x] = it doesn't matter what's here
$array1[2][0] = 3;
$array1[2][x] = it doesn't matter what's here
...
```

how to sort second array so it would have same values as array1 on indexes [0][0], [1][0], [2][0], etc.

How I could solve problem is:

```
$i=0
while ($i < (count($array1)-2)){ // * check down

  $find_id = $array1[$i][0];

  // here I need to search for index of that ID in other array
  $position = give_index($find_id, $array2);

  // swapping positions
  $temp = array2[$i][0];
  $array2[$i][0] = $array2[$position][0];
  $array2[$position][0] = $temp;

  // increasing counter
  i++;
}

function give_index($needle, $haystack){
  for ($j = 0, $l = count($haystack); $j < $l; ++$j) {
        if (in_array($needle, $haystack[$j][0])) return $j;
  }
  return false;
}
```

- *There is only -2 because indexes start from 0 and also for the last element you don't need to check since it would be automatically sorted by last iteration of while-loop.

I don't find this solution good as I think that this is quite simple issue (maybe it's not even correct). Is there easier way in PHP that I'm missing?

Comment: Would would the second array look like?

Comment: Same as array1 - the thing is in these IDs which are always on [i][0] where "i" are all indexes that could be there. That needs to be equal, in other words

array1[0][0] = array2[0][0], array1[1][0] = array2[1][0].

for other elements, such as array1[0][x] which x is whatever, it doesn't matter, because whole dimension (if it should be said like this) or rather nested array should be swapped in array2. Do you get it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most efficient way I can think of:

```
function swap(&$a, &$b) { 
    $t = $a;
    $a = $b;
    $b = $t;
}

function find_index($id, $array, $from = 0) {
    $index = false;
    for ($i = $from, $c = count($array); $i < $c; $i++) {
        if ($array[$i][0] == $id) {
            $index = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $index;
}

for ($i = 0, $c = count($array1); $i < ($c - 2); $i++) {
    if ($array1[$i][0] != $array2[$i][0]) {
        $fi = find_index($array1[$i][0], $array2, $i);
        swap($array2[$i][0], $array2[$fi][0]);
    }
}
```

**What changes from yours?**

- I've defined a `swap()` function in order to swap any variable. That doesn't cost anything and makes everything look nicer. Also you can reuse that function later if you need to.
- In the `find_index` (`give_index` in your code) we stop the loop once we find the correct index. Also we avoid the cost of an `in_array` function call.
- We modified the `find_index` function to start only from the part of the array we haven't checked yet. Leading to a way more efficient way of scan the array.
- In the for loop (a `while` loop was just wrong there) we stored the `count` of the array once, avoiding multiple calls.
- Also we swap the `$array2` values only if they are in the wrong place.

**Other improvements**

If you know anything else of the `$array2` array you can make this even more performant. For example if you know that indexes are alternated like in `$array1` you can change the main for loop from:

```
for ($i = 0, $c = count($array1); $i < ($c - 2); $i++) {
```

to

```
for ($i = 0, $c = count($array1); $i < ($c - 2); $i+2) {
```

(notice the `$i+2` at the end) And you could do that in the `find_index` function as well.

Comment: Wow, thanks for great explanation and effort. Still, it doesn't work for some reason. It sorts first, but then it doesn't sort after.

Can it be because I'm swapping actually nested arrays? I just made 3 lines (because array2[$i] is actually nested array in array2 containing 3 elements on indexes 0, 1 and 2) for every element in array2[$i], and now it looks like:
  `swap($array2[$i][0], $array2[$fi][0]);
  swap($array2[$i][1], $array2[$fi][1]);
  swap($array2[$i][2], $array2[$fi][2]);` but it still doesn't work :\

Comment: Ok, I got it! You wouldn't believe where "we" made mistake (mostly me because I said that it can go < (c-2) but by that I meant on <= (c-2) :). So actually, it's only like $i < (c-1) because this < already means that it won't reach till that number, which is perfect for indexes starting from 0. 

Anyways, thanks you a lot for explanation and time, everything works great!

Comment: @Tommz, Sorry I din't see your comment before. If everything is all right then you are welcome sir.

Answer (score 0):

Look into usort (http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

It provides a simple way to sort arrays using a user provided comparison function.